# Почему не работает (Fatal error: Unsupported operand types)?

Tags: php, mysql

Вот код :

```
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE poluchatel='$user_email' GROUP BY author desc", $db);
$messages1 = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE author='$user_email' GROUP BY poluchatel desc", $db); 
$messages2 = mysql_fetch_array($tmp);

$messages = $messages1 + $messages2;
```

При выполнении вот такая проблема:

> `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types в строчке $messages = $messages1 + $messages2;`

Почему?

Comment: почитайте про mysql_fetch_array:     
1) что она возвращает   
2) как ней пользоваться
3) и что Вы вообще хотите сложить, не понятно. (конкатенировать в php "." точкой)

Comment: Ну какая конкатенация массивов? Вы что?

Comment: Типичный недостаток языков начала 21 века.

Comment: >>>Ну какая конкатенация массивов? Вы что?>>>

        
я не о массивах вообще говорил, а о конкатенации в php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А с каких это пор массивы стало можно складывать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php

Comment: $a + $b - Объединение массива $a и массива $b.   
Это так, для справки

Comment: Складывание и объединение это вроде не одно и тоже.
Сложить значит, если в одинаковых индексах числовой тип он суммируется. Если там строка то конкатенируется и.т.д И формируется новый массив.

А объединить, значит например для ассоциативного массива создать массив, включающий все уникальные индексы обоих.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае объединение массивов не происходит, потому что один из операндов не является массивом.

Если **array() + array()** возможно, то, например **array() + 0** приведет к

**Fatal error**:  Unsupported operand types in..